# Can i use TDAudioStreamer with GCDAsyncSocket or NetService?

Tags: ios, swift, audio-streaming, gcdasyncsocket, nsnetservice

I want to stream audio file between to multiple device, one act as server and other as client on the local network, I found https://github.com/tonyd256/TDAudioStreamer this class that stream audio to connected client but it use multiplier connectivity. I wonder that, can I use this class with **GCDAsyncSocket** or **NetService** if there is any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as my experience you have to pass stream object to this classes in order to work with GCDAsyncSocket or NetService. Then after client side receiving data from server you have to convert that data in proper format to play.
That's all i know.